# After Log out and new login, still shows old user data

Tags: flutter, authentication

I have made an app using Flutter. As I log out, app starts from onBoarding page and when new user logs in, it still shows old user data. But when I restart after killing the app, it works! new user data is visible properly. So the issue is that it doesn't show new user data while app is running but shows up when killed and restarted. I have cleared shared preferences and also tried deleting cache through code.

```
     clearLoggedIn() async {
        prefs.remove('hasLoggedIn');
        prefs.clear();
         _deleteCacheDir();
      }

Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
 final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

 if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
   cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
 }
}
```

Comment: There is clearly a problem on your onBoarding page, not rebuilding or not with the correct data source

Comment: I am having this same problem in my flutter app, have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Any solution found i fetch same issue?

Comment: Is your "user data" saved in shared preferences or is it stored in memory in some state management package?